# Bundler and hidden gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I have an interesting error when installing gems directly from github (`:git => 'whatever'`).

Firstly, when I remove all gems and run **bundle install** command, I get the following:

```
Installing gem1
Installing gem2
Using gem3 (the one from github)
```

Then when I want to check what I've got I see the following by using **gem list**:

```
gem1 (x.x.x)
gem2 (y.y.y)
```

No gem3... now, looking closer to the file system, I see the following:

```
ls -l ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems
gem1
gem2
```

So where is gem 3? Not where I'm expecting it to be:

```
ls -l ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bundler/gems
gem3-213213213
```

So it goes under bundler/gems and is not visible to **gem list**... and by Capistrano deploy, which gives me following:

```
git://github.com/author/gem3.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

I'm more worried about Capistrano unable to deploy... Anyone has any clues?

Comment: Are you not running `bundle install` when deploying?

Comment: Yep I'm running bundle install during deployment.  I removed all gems and run bundle install directly for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler gets its gems from various sources on your system. As long as they are the correct version, it will pull them in.

When deploying, it has more strict/conservative behavior.

From `bundle help install`, in the section about **Deployment Mode**, which is used when the `--deployment` flag is specified:

> Gems  are  installed to vendor/bundle not your default system loca-
>   tion
>
> In development, it's convenient to share  the  gems  used  in  your
>   application  with  other  applications and other scripts run on the
>   system.
>
> In deployment, isolation is a more important default. In  addition,
>   the  user  deploying  the  application  may  not have permission to
>   install gems to the system, or the web server may not have  permis-
>   sion to read them.
>
> As  a result, bundle install --deployment installs gems to the ven-
>   dor/bundle directory in the application.  This  may  be  overridden
>   using the --path option.

Comment: I guess I was fighting the losing battle by trying to make system to use system-wide gems.  Your solution with deployment flag works, so I will stick by it! Thanks.